# ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) wine midi has no output

Tags: 12.04, wine, output, midi

I have UBUNTU 12.04 (KXStudio version) with several MIDI programs that work well both input and output. I installed Wine 1.5.31 so I could run Studio4 by Midisoft. The program runs, accepting MIDI input from my MIDI keyboard. It cannot play the MIDI file back. I assumed there was a problem with Studio4 so I installed MidiPiano. This give the a good input/output result after I configured the options "a2jnidid - port" and "USB UNO MIDI Interface MIDI 1". When I try to configure Studio4 the same way, wine will not let me. I insists on connecting input to "MIDI Through Port 0". Thus the application does not play.

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synth MIDI in apps under Wine you need a MIDI synth in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install timidity freepats
```

Sources: http://www.earmaster.com/community/topic.html?p=1638#p1638 ; http://wiki.winehq.org/MIDI