# How To Connect Akai MPK Mini with PreSonus Studio One in Wine?

Tags: wine, midi

I am using PreSonus Studio One Professional 2.5 with Wine. My computer recognizes the MPK Mini, but it doesn't work within Studio One. I've searched the internet looking for a driver or something that I can install to help Studio One see the device. I haven't had any luck so I decided I would ask the community. I am fairly new to linux (about 5 months in) so forgive my ignorance. If you need any additional information to help answer my question, feel free to ask!

Thanks!

Comment: also,here http://askubuntu.com/a/306628/167115 says to install timidity as well